# How to get specific (grand parent) category of current post?

Tags: categories, loop

I am having a category hierarchy with three levels.

My example:

```markdown
- Top-Level Cat 1
  - Sub1A
    - Subchild1A1
    - Subchild1A2
  - Sub1B
    - Subchild1B1
    - Subchild1B2
- Top-Level Cat 2
  - Sub2A
    - Subchild2A1
    - Subchild2A2
  - Sub2B
    - Subchild2B1
    - Subchild2B2
...
```

For visualization top level categories are continents, the sub-categories are countries and the subchild categories are cities.

Now my posts have all three categories (continent, country, city). I want to display the country (for example Sub1A) of a post. How is this possible? With `get_the_category` I get all three categories but always in a different (alphabetical?) order. Can I solve this to get the correct category (country - the "grandparent" category)?

Comment: Would the post always contain just the three categories, namely continent, country and city? Have you considered using custom taxonomies, so for example you would have a taxonomy named `city` and `country`?

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes every post hast the three categories and the three categories are hierarchical continent > country > city. there will be no other category levels. I never used custom taxonomies. I will have a look :)

Comment: So have you looked at it? What you think? Would you still like to try with a possible solution for the default `category` taxonomy?